# How to identify which application upgrades regularly in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, update-manager

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and I connect with internet through mobile WiFi hotspot. In the updates section in software and updates application I chosen as never updates automatically and updates as every two weeks. But 2-4 days once while I connect internet with the system means my mobile data start consume more data with out doing any operation. If I disconnect with the system then mobile data stop consume. By that I identify as system only consumes more data. But I couldn't identify where or which application consume those data? I referred many sources, but still no exact solution I found. Guide me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify: What leads you to believe that upgrades are responsible the the excessive data consumption? How exactly did you "stop the auto update?"

Comment: In software and updates program there is a section to choose how often it checks.  I guess you would want never(bad idea).  Ubuntu and most Linux sends out updates almost daily for the OS and all programs you have, only a bit each time so your system would be completely updated every couple of months.  You can adjust the timing of updates from daily to once every two weeks.

Comment: @ user535733 and crip659: Thanks for your responses. As per your suggestion I edit the question. Please go through it and guide me to solve the issue. thanks..

Comment: Any solutions for the above mentioned situations?